# How to maximize CPU utilization in tensorflow GPU training with Dataset API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using the new dataset api to train a simple feed-forward DL model. I am interested in maximizing training speed. Since my network size isn't huge, as expected I see low GPU utilization. That is fine. But what I don't understand is why CPU usage is also far from 100%. I am using a multi-cpu/gpu core machine. Currently I get up to 140 steps / sec where batch_size = 128. If I cache the dataset I can get up to 210 steps (after initial scan). So I expect that with sufficient prefetching, I should be able to reach the same speed without caching. However with various prefetching and prefetch_to_device parameters, I cannot get more than 140 steps / sec. I also set num_parallel_calls to the number of cpu cores, which improves by about 20%.

Ideally I'd like the prefetching thread to be on a disjoint cpu core from the rest of the input pipeline, so that whatever benefit it provides is strictly additive. But from the cpu usage profiling I suspect that the prefetching and input processing occur on every core:

[image]

Is there a way to have more control over cpu allocation? I have tried prefetch(1), prefetch(500), and several other values (right after batch or at the end of the dataset construction), as well as in combination with prefetch_to_device(gpu_device, batch_size = None, 1, 500, etc). So far prefetch(500) without prefetch_to_device works the best.

Why doesn't prefetch try to exhaust all the cpu power on my machine? What are other possible bottlenecks in training speed?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [`Dataset.prefetch(buffer_size)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch) transformation adds *pipeline* parallelism and (bounded) buffering to your input pipeline. Therefore, increasing the `buffer_size` may increase the fraction of time when the input to the `Dataset.prefetch()` is running (because the buffer is more likely to have free space), but it does not increase the speed at which the input runs (and hence the CPU usage).

Typically, to increase the speed of the pipeline and increase CPU usage, you would add *data* parallelism by adding `num_parallel_calls=N` to any [`Dataset.map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) transformations, and you might also consider using [`tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/parallel_interleave) to process many input sources concurrently and avoid blocking on I/O.

The [`tf.data` Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance) has more details about how to improve the performance of input pipelines, including these suggestions.

Comment: Thanks @mrry! I have read the Performance Guide pretty thoroughly. The only thing I haven't tried is parallel_interleave. But I checked my disk IO and it appears not to be the bottleneck (e.g., if I run two concurrent training jobs, I can get more steps per second total than running only one job, even though each one is slightly slower). My understanding about num_parallel_calls is that it should be set to no more than the number of virtual cores, which is what I have done. I have tried setting it to higher value and that didn't help. I will report back on parallel_interleave and data sharing.

Comment: I found out that using parallel_interleave only slowed down my training by about 10%. This is probably because my files are stored locally rather than on remote hdfs etc. Also disk io doesn't seem to be the bottleneck from top. I wonder if mutex locking is the culprit for cpu under-usage: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/583? Thanks again!